# why the new compiled g++ say "ld: cannot find -lg++"

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I wanted a old gcc version 2.7.2.3 with Redhat Linux 9.0 and gcc 2.95.3 and [gcc-2.7.2.3.tar.gz](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/gcc/gcc-2.7.2.3.tar.gz), and used the following commands:

```
./configure --prefix=target-dir
make bootstrap LANGUAGES="c c++" BOOT_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
make install
```

after that, I can use the **gcc-2.7.2.3** to compile **c** program , but the **g++-2.7.2.3** did not work, when I compiled the following simplest c++ program:

```
//test.cc
int main() {return 0;}
```

using the command:

```
g++-2.7.2.3 test.cc
ld: cannot find -lg++
```

however, I can use the following commands to finish it:

```
g++-2.7.2.3 -c test.cc
gcc-2.7.2.3 -o test test.o
```

what should I do for modifying this error? any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the output of the compiler invocations with the `-v` flag? I suspect `g++-2.7.2.3` is picking up the wrong linker.

Comment: You might need more than just `gcc` for this, possibly even an entire toolchain (`libstdc++`, `binutils`, etc.).  You might be able to install RH 9.0 in a VM and build that way.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier I got the following msg:                           Reading specs from /home/abelard/builtTools/gcc-2.723//lib/gcc-lib/i686-unknown-linux/2.7.2.3/specs
gcc version 2.7.2.3

Comment: @ldav1s I used vmware to do these, as you said, I also used **gcc-2.7.3** to compile libg++-2.7.2.tar.bz2, and with this libg++'s libstdc++, I have compiled tktree(A Tree Widget for Tk4.0 based on C++ and [incr Tcl]) and got a tktree.a, I also need compile the appropriate binutils?

Comment: @abelard20008, probably you'll need to build a toolchain.  gcc-2.7.2.3 was last in RH 5.2.  Even though you're on an old distro, there's a _lot_ of changes that happened in gcc from 5.2 to 9.0.

Comment: @ldav1s thanks, you are great, my old programs can be compiled successfully in RH5.2, but my RH5.2 could not run X Window in vmware and qemu, so I want to build a whole toolchain in 9.0, up to now, I have already finished [gcc-2.7.2.3.tar.gz](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/gcc/gcc-2.7.2.3.tar.gz)(looks like gcc was ok), [libc++-2.7.2.tar.bz2](http://ftp.vim.org/languages/gcc/old-releases/libg++/libg++-2.7.2.tar.bz2), what else I need for getting a whole **toolchain**, binutils, or egcs?

Comment: @ldav1s Just now, I thought about the whole toolchain and the relation between the inner components (gcc-2.7.23.tar.gz and binutils) ,and checked the gcc/g++-2.7.2.3 correspond to the RH5.0. so that, I guess that I need an appropriate binutis's ld for g++-2.7.2.3,but I do not know why gcc-2.7.2.3 does not need it? another side, If I use this old binutils to finish the work, the generated ELF file will not be able to run in RH9.0?

Comment: @abelard20008, AFAICT, programs won't work going from RHL 5.0 to RHL 9.0.  I tried it, building a simple test program on Slackware 3.2 with g++ 2.7.2.1 (I couldn't find an ISO of RHL 5.0).  This program runs on RHL 5.2, but not on RHL 9.0.  I can't even run `ldd` on the program in RHL 9.0 -- I get `/lib/ld-linux.so.1: bad ELF interpreter` and no list of other libs it's linked to.

Comment: The fact that the output program of the cross toolchain won't run on RHL 9.0 isn't very important.  _It needs to run on RHL 5.0_.  Reading the info about [crosstool](http://kegel.com/crosstool/) might be helpful, but unfortunately not directly applicable (the RHL 5.0 compiler is older, as is the linux kernel).  In order to build the cross toolchain gcc, glibc, binutils, and linux kernel headers from RHL 5.0 need to be built on the build machine (in this case RHL 9.0) for the RHL 5.0 host.  EGCS was an experimental fork of gcc, you won't need it if you're using gcc.

Comment: @ldav1s Thanks a lot, your explanation refresh my knowledge about toolchain. but in my case, I only need gcc-2.7.2.3 and g++-2.7.2.3 because I hope the final ELF files can run on RH9.0, and my old programs are able to be compiled successfully on RH5.2(sadly, RH5.2's X Window could not work for lack of available VGA driver in vmare and qemu describing in [my another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23547437/1054800)) . and finally, I got the version 2.7.2.3's ELF of my old programs in RH9.0 through using gcc-2.7.2.3 to produce finally ELF after g++-2.7.2.3's object files

Comment: @ldav1s, also sadly, in RH9.0, my final ELF of old programs from gcc-2.7.2.3 got a **segment fault** when calling RH9.0's XOpenDisplay of Xlib. all these questions I met forced me giving up building RH5.2's X Window or building gcc 2.7.2.3 in RH9.0, finally I choose modifying my old programs, now they can work after one day's work mainly including some syntax correction for RH9.0's gcc 2.96

Answer (score 0):

Maybe g++ library(lib) directory is missing.